# Use batch script to insert a string at a particular line in XML

Tags: xml, string, batch-file, insert, newline

i am new to programming.
Can some1 kindly teach me how to insert a new line in an XML file using batch script?
Current file has first 2 lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xxxxxxxxx
```

I want to add a format string on Line 2 so it has:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xxxxxxxxxx
```

It has to be using batch-file as the rest of the file is built with it.

Cheers,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "secondLine=^<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?^>"
    (for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.xml) do (
        echo(%%a
        if defined secondLine ( 
            echo(%secondLine%
            set "secondLine="
        )
    )) > output.xml
```

Comment: so how do i make this work for other line numbers? what if i want to insert into the 12th or the 23rd line how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on Windows. If you do not already have Unix [Utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), I would recommend grabbing that first and adding it to your `PATH`.

You can then do

```
 sed "1 a <?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>" Input.xml > Output.xml
 move Output.xml Input.xml
```

Note that the Windows version of `sed` may not support the `-i` option, but if it does, you can shorten this to

```
sed -i "1 a <?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>" Input.xml
```

Comment: thx Merlin, yes, I am using Window 7 on company PC, but it seems it automatically delete the files after I downloaded and extracted them.