# Insert text at a particular line number in a text file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to insert a string of text say "hello" in a particular line say n (12 or 23 or some other number) using batch script. I know batch script is bad but unfortunately the requirement for this is batch script.

Here's what I've tried

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "nthline=TEXT"
(for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (c.txt) do (
    echo(%%a
    if defined nthline ( 
        echo(%nthline%
        set "nthline="
    )
))
```

This code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976323/use-batch-script-to-insert-a-string-at-a-particular-line-in-xml?answertab=votes#tab-top) but it only inserts to the **second line** I cannot make it go beyond that.

Here is what the text file contains

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
ffff
gggg
hhhh
```

It inserts the string after aaaa. How can I make it insert at bbbb or ffff  I'm new to batch scripting so Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write batch variable into specific line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686261/write-batch-variable-into-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: yes it does thank you very much *tips fedora*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted is designed to insert an extra line after the first one.

To insert at a certain point you need to somehow predefine the target line number and a line number, then compare these numbers for equality and return the extra line of text ‐ line in the following script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constante here:
set "_FILE=c.txt" & rem // (text file to insert a line of text into)
set "_TEXT=hello" & rem // (text of the inserted line)
set /A "_NUM=4"   & rem // (number of the line where the new line is inserted)
set "_REPLAC=#"   & rem // (set to anything to replace the target line, or to nothing to keep it)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path and name of temporary file)

rem // Write result into temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Loop through all lines of the text file, each with a preceding line number:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Store current line including preceding line number to a variable:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Set the current line number to another variable:
        set /A "LNUM=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Compare current line number with predefined one:
        if !LMUN! equ %_NUM% (
            rem // Line numbers match, so return extra line of text:
            echo(!_TEXT!
            rem // Return original line (without preceding line number) only if it is not to be replaced:
            if not defined _REPLAC echo(!LINE:*:=!
        ) else (
            rem // Line numbers do not match, so return original line (without preceding line number) anyway:
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Move temporary file onto original one:
move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: @ Prabhjot Singh Kainth linked the answer in the first comment that seemed to work and it's almost the same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

some revising on the aschipfl solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constante here:
set "_FILE=c.txt" & rem // (text file to insert a line of text into)
set "_TEXT=hello" & rem // (text of the inserted line)
set /A "_NUM=4"   & rem // (number of the line where the new line is inserted)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path and name of temporary file)

rem // Write result into temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Loop through all lines of the text file, each with a preceding line number:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"`) do (
        rem // Store current line including preceding line number to a variable:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Set the current line number to another variable:
        set /A "LNUM=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Compare current line number with predefined one:
        if !LNUM! equ %_NUM% (
            rem // Line numbers match, so return extra line of text:
            echo !_TEXT!
        ) else (
            rem // Line numbers do not match, so return original line (without preceding line number) anyway:
            rem // remove the left leading spaces
            for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%s in ("!LINE:*:=!") do set tl=%%s
            if "!tl!" == "" (
                echo:
            ) else (
                echo !LINE:*:=!
            )

        )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Move temporary file onto original one:
move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

this is a little simpler and working version so to speak. notice the back ticks in for/loop